# Not able to fetch the record if only one record is present, using QSqlite

Tags: qt

I am trying to fetch the records from the table. I am able to get all the records except the first record.

Same way if there is only one record, then that record is also not fetched.

How could I get the only record present in my table.

I am using Qt, QSqlite and trying to get the records using QSqlQuery.next() function.

Like:

```
while(query.next())
```

What should I do to get all the records?

Comment: You'll need to show more code, `while(query.next()) { ... }` is the right way to do it, select queries are positioned "before the first record" after `exec`. So that type of loop should work, it's actually documented that way in the QSqlQuery docs.

Comment: Edit your question to add the details (use the `{}` button to format code). It's completely unreadable in comments.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add the details, your comments are completely unreadable.

Comment: Sorry my bad.Actually I have only 1 record like:UserId = 1 and Name = Naveen.To get this record I tried like:
{
strQuery = QString("select Name from User_Table where UserID = 1"); 
if (!ExecuteQuery(strQuery, sqlQuery)) 
{ 
     qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastError(); 
     return false; 
} 
while (sqlQuery.next()) 
{ 
     QString strName = sqlQuery.value(0).toString(); 
} 
}
This way I didn't get the Name Naveen.I tried to debug, but that while loop never executes

Comment: I am not able to put the codes in correct format... please copy the code i have posted to get...Thanks

Comment: **Edit your question**. **Do not post code in comments**.

Answer (score 0):

try to place the function QSqlQuery.first() before the while it place the db pointer to the first record so it should work.